# What is the power series expansion at $x=0$ of the algebraic function defined by $(27x-4)y^3 + 3y + 1 = 0$?

Tags: power-series, generating-functions, algebraic-curves, formal-power-series

Let $y$ denote the complex-valued algebraic function defined implicitly near $x=0$ by $(27x - 4)y^3 + 3y + 1=0$ and such that $y(0)=1$. What is the power series expansion of this function at $x=0$? The first few terms are
$$
y = 1 + 3x + 15x^2 + 84x^3 + 495x^4 + \cdots
$$

I have a couple of ideas about how to approach this problem, but none of them have panned out.

- *Use implicit differentiation to compute $y^{(n)}(0)$ recursively*. You'll end up with the equation
  $$
  (27x-4)\sum_{i+j+k=n}\binom{n}{i,j,k}y^{(i)}(0)\cdot y^{(j)}(0)\cdot y^{(k)}(0) + 27\sum_{i+j+k=n-1}\binom{n}{1,i,j,k}y^{(i)}(0)\cdot y^{(j)}(0)\cdot y^{(k)}(0) + 3y^{(n)} = 0,
  $$
  which could then be used to compute $y^{(n)}(0)$ recursively. But this equation looks prohibitively complicated.
- *Use the cubic formula to compute an explicit formula for $y$ near $x=0$*. I don't like this method because it wouldn't generalize to algebraic functions of higher degree. Also, I'm not that familiar with the cubic equation.
- *Substitute an indeterminate power series into the equation defining $y$ and solve recursively for the coefficients*. But it seems too difficult to compute the power series expansion of $y^3$ from the power series expansion of $y$. It also seems like this won't generalize to the higher-degree case.

More broadly, does the general version of this problem -- compute the power series expansion of a given algebraic function about a given point -- have an algorithmic solution? What if we work over a different field than $\mathbb C$?

I'd prefer a closed-form expression for the coefficients of the power series, but a recurrence relation is almost as good. For the general problem, I expect that finding a recurrence relation is the best we can do.

Comment: You can try using Lagrange inversion.

Comment: Note that the equation $4y^3-3y-1=0$ has the solution $y=1$ (taken care of in the answers below), but also the double solution $y=-{1\over2}$. This gives rise to two more algebraic branches of your "function" near $x=0$.

Comment: The above $\color{#f00}{184}$ coef$\ldots$ must be $\color{#f00}{84}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin You're right; I corrected it. The mistake was carried over from my source.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example), the solution of $w^3-w=-x$ has the following Taylor series:
$$ w(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{3k}{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} $$
whose radius of convergence is $\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$. If we set $y(x)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4-27 x}}\,w(x)$, by Lagrange inversion:

> $$ y(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{3k}{k}\frac{3(-1)^k}{(2k+1)(4-27x)^{k+1}}\tag{1}$$

and we may apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to recover the coefficients of the Taylor series as convolutions.

If you show that your function $y$ fulfills $y=w'(\sqrt{x})$, with $w$ being the solution of $w^3-w=-x$, you prove Robert Israel's extraordinary simple claim:

> $$ y(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{3k}{k}x^k .\tag{2}$$

It is probably easier to go in the opposite direction: take $w(x)$ as the solution of $w^3-w=-x$, define $y$ as $w'(\sqrt{x})$ and show by differentiation that $y$ is a solution of $(27x-4)y^3+3y+1=0$.

Still another way is to show that

> $$ y(x)=\frac{2\cdot\cos\left(\frac{1}{3} \arcsin\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3x}}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4-27 x}}\tag{3}$$

by solving the original third-degree equation through Chebyshev polynomials, then finding the Taylor coefficients of $(3)$ through Euler's beta function, leading to $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty {3k \choose k} x^k$$

See [OEIS sequence A005809](https://oeis.org/A005809)

Comment: How did you arrive at this answer? It's similar to Jack D'Aruzio's, but simpler.

Comment: I computed the first $30$ coefficients and looked it up in the OEIS.

Comment: Ah, I figured! Ok. This is mysterious then . . .

Comment: @user134824: not that mysterious, just a very well-hidden change of variable in a differential equation.

Comment: Which differential equation?

Comment: @user134824: please see my updated answer.